# Wiered "[ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file..." "cannot be resolved to a type" in gwt gradle

Tags: gwt, gradle

I have a series of interdependent GWT projects, all the chain compiles fine, but the last element seems to be unable to read java classes from the generated dependent jars :

I checked the jar in the error, the .java and .class files are really there where they are supposed to be : it's amazing that the compiler finds the jar containing the wanted class

> ShopAdmin-1.0.jar

but it doesn't read it (this is the case for many classes, see 
[the compilation output](https://14153982395699982549.googlegroups.com/attach/748645ee13864/build.txt?part=0.1&view=1&vt=ANaJVrFE6T1nNoiYHsyzaTV9Ai-gx33QVEw8lg82vT24LyEQo6iFwxhMT1f0F8VKPELXqeqr3QNXZ8aYK32Un1tDEqps8M_ElaUhSnaHqyawWWCB57L1cMw) )

```
 [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/Users/Zied%20Hamdi/git/VuMe/ShopAdmin/build/libs/ShopAdmin-1.0.jar!/fr/onevu/vume/shopadmin/ShopAdmin.java'
            [ERROR] fr.onevu.vume.shopadmin.ShopAdminClientFactory cannot be resolved to a type
```

You can see that

> ShopAdminClientFactory.java is in the same package as ShopAdmin.java

```
 R‚pertoire de c:\temp\ShopAdmin-1.0\fr\onevu\vume\shopadmin

25/10/2016  22:00    <REP>          .
25/10/2016  22:00    <REP>          ..
25/10/2016  22:00    <REP>          activity
25/10/2016  22:00    <REP>          activitymappers
25/10/2016  21:43               856 ContentManager$1.class
25/10/2016  21:43             1ÿ836 ContentManager.class
23/09/2016  19:29               988 ContentManager.java
25/10/2016  22:00    <REP>          i18n
25/10/2016  22:00    <REP>          request
25/10/2016  21:43             1ÿ225 ShopAdmin$1.class
25/10/2016  21:43             1ÿ112 ShopAdmin$2.class
25/10/2016  21:43             6ÿ486 ShopAdmin.class
23/09/2016  19:29             5ÿ439 ShopAdmin.java
25/10/2016  21:43             1ÿ488 ShopAdminActivityManager$1.class
25/10/2016  21:43             2ÿ907 ShopAdminActivityManager.class
27/09/2016  12:59             1ÿ962 ShopAdminActivityManager.java
25/10/2016  21:43             4ÿ466 ShopAdminClientFactory.class
23/09/2016  19:29             2ÿ838 ShopAdminClientFactory.java
25/10/2016  21:43            11ÿ472 ShopAdminClientFactoryImpl.class
23/09/2016  19:29             7ÿ249 ShopAdminClientFactoryImpl.java
25/10/2016  21:43             1ÿ638 ShopAdminEnvironment$1.class
25/10/2016  21:43             7ÿ853 ShopAdminEnvironment.class
23/09/2016  19:29             4ÿ060 ShopAdminEnvironment.java
25/10/2016  21:43             1ÿ476 ShopAdminFacade.class
23/09/2016  19:29               794 ShopAdminFacade.java
25/10/2016  21:43             1ÿ426 ShopAdminPlaceController.class
23/09/2016  19:29             1ÿ024 ShopAdminPlaceController.java
25/10/2016  22:00    <REP>          view
              21 fichier(s)           68ÿ595 octets

 R‚pertoire de c:\temp\ShopAdmin-1.0\fr\onevu\vume\shopadmin\activity
```

Also, the project Customer (that is being compiled) doesn't contain ShopAdmin.java, this file is in a dependent project (Customer is depending to all other projects). What is bizarre is that when compiling Customer, the error is about a class that is not in Customer but in its direct dependency ShopAdmin (a customer is always a shop admin).

```
/**
 * app engine conf found on https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/gradle
 */

group = 'fr.onevu.vume'
version = '1.0'

apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'gwt'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'jetty'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine'  // App Engine tasks


//Java version compatibility to use when compiling Java source.
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
//Java version to generate classes for.
targetCompatibility = 1.7

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter() //repository where to fetch gwt gradle plugin
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.6'
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:+'    // latest App Engine Gradle tasks
    }
}

// central repository to load the GWT library
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven-central.storage.googleapis.com'             // Google's mirror of Maven Central
        //   url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' // SNAPSHOT Repository (if needed)
    }

    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.appengine/gradle-appengine-plugin
    compile group: 'com.google.appengine', name: 'gradle-appengine-plugin', version: '1.9.42'
    compile project(':VuMetest')

    // needed for Maps API
    compile group: 'com.google.gwt.google-apis', name: 'gwt-ajaxloader', version: '1.0.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.gwt/gwt-user
    compile group: 'com.google.gwt', name: 'gwt-user', version: '2.7.0'

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}


gwt {
    gwtVersion='2.7.0'
    modules 'fr.onevu.vume.ShopAdmin'

    logLevel = 'ERROR'

    minHeapSize = "1024M";
    maxHeapSize = "2048M";

    superDev {
        noPrecompile=true
    }

    // The following is only needed if you don't use the Google Plugin for Eclipse.
    eclipse{
        addGwtContainer=true // Default set to true
    }

    //Specify the deployment Port
    jettyRunWar.httpPort = 8089
}

jar {
  manifest {
    attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'IntoGwt', 'Implementation-Version': version
  }
  from project.sourceSets.main.allJava
  from('src/main/java') {
    include '**/*.xml'
    include '**/*.css'
    include '**/*.png'
    include '**/*.properties'
    exclude '**JUnit**'
  }

}
```

but the generated jar file has everything in place : the uncompresses jar contains the class there where it is supposed to be :

Any ideas?

Best reagrds,
Zied

Answer (score 1):

Ok!

That was my fault, I didn't have to resolve dependencies manually for a while. It was just a classpath problem (of a jar added manually because it's not available on maven)

I just had to follow the unresolved symbols causes chain until I found the dependency on // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.gwt.google-apis/gwt-ajaxloader
compile group: 'com.google.gwt.google-apis', name: 'gwt-ajaxloader', version: '1.1.0' was not added

Comment: this removed a bad dependency on my tree 
 compile ('com.github.branflake2267:gwt-maps-api:3.10.0-alpha-7') {
  exclude group: 'com.google.gwt'
 }